# In which direction do the perihelions of the planets show? Is this somehow correlated with the solar apex?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, sun

I just found a Wikipedia page that showed that almost all perihelion where at the same position (except for Mars) and I was wondering, if someone has more information /data/pictures. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [longitude of perihelion of the planets](http://www.met.rdg.ac.uk/%7Eross/Astronomy/Planets.html) does not appear to be anything but random$^1$. That is unsurprising since the perihelion advances with time at significant but different rates for the planets, so that any alignment now would quickly be lost. [For example](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/lectures/node115.html), the perihelion of the Earth will have rotated by 180 degrees in the next 57,000 years, while the perihelion of Mercury will have rotated through about 90 degrees in the same time.

The solar apex is at an ecliptic latitude of 53 degrees, so could hardly be related to the orbits of the planets.

$^1$ You can of course play games by excluding a planet (in this case Mars) that seems to be an odd one out based on your hypothesised relationship, but that is hardly a valid statistical exercise if trying to show something is non-random. Even allowing this, the angle between the longitude of perihelion for Jupiter and Uranus is 156 degrees!